Find all positive integer $n$ such that $\tau(n) = \sqrt{n+1}$
Find all positive integer $n$ such that $\tau(n) = \sqrt{n+1}$
$\tau(n)$ is the function that count the number of positive divisor of $n$ includes $n$ and $1$
For example $\tau(3)=2, \tau(8) = 4, \tau(p^k) = k+1, \tau(15) = 4$
Here is what I got:

$n$ can't be a perfect square which leads to $\tau(n)$ is even
$n = (\tau(n)-1)(\tau(n)+1)$

If $n$ is a square-free number then it will lead to contradiction by put
$$n=p_1p_2\ldots p_k \Rightarrow \tau(n) = 2^k = \sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{2^{2k}+1} > 2^k$$
And I try some case with $n=3,n=15$
And I also find that $n=a(a+2)$ with $a$ is an odd number
Can anyone help me solve the case when $n$ is not a square free number please? Thank you a lots.

$$ \tau(n) \leq 48 \left(\frac{n}{2520}\right)^{1/3} $$

Why don't you prove that yourself?  Given the fact that it does have a maximum, find the integer $n$  for which $\frac{\tau(n)}{n^{1/3}}$  achieves its maximum.  That is to say, for each prime $p,$   find the $p^k$  that gives maximizes that ratio; then $n$ is the product of those $p^k.$  For all but a finite set of (small) $p$ the exponent $k$ that works best is $k=0$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number

It's easy to prove by induction that $k+1\leq 3^{k/2}$ for all $k\neq 1$ (note that for $k=1$ we have $2<\sqrt 3$) and that $k+1\leq 5^{k/2}$ for all $k$. So if $\nu_3(n)\neq 1$, remembering that $n$ is odd (as you proved), given the factorization $n=\prod p_k^{a_k}$ we have
$$\tau(n)=\prod (a_k+1)\leq \prod p_k^{a_k/2}=\sqrt n<\sqrt{n+1}.$$
For $\nu_3(n)=1$ we can prove again by induction that $\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}(k+1)\leq 7^{k/2}$ for $k\geq 1$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}(k+1)\leq 5^{k/2}$ for $k\geq 2$. So if $\nu_5(n)\geq 2$ or $n$ has a prime divisor greater than $5$ we conclude again that $\tau(n)\leq \sqrt n<\sqrt{n+1}$. The only cases left are $n=3, 15$ and they both work.

A simple method is to use the fact that $\tau(n)$ grows more slowly than any power of $n$. Various explicit estimates of this type exist, which will reduce the problem to a finite computation. For example, equation (4) of this Sándor paper tells us that
$$
\tau(n) < \sqrt n \quad\text{for}\quad n\ge1{,}262.
$$
Examining the remaining $1{,}261$ candidates one by one confirms that $n=3,15$ are the only solutions to $\tau(n)=\sqrt{n+1}$.
